# How do I make a list of DB data from jsp and print it out?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, spring

I am in the beginning stage of `web` development.

I can get the `DBdata` but I'm not sure how to **print it out as a list**.

I'm printing out **this table list**.

```sql
        SELECT
        seq_no,
        type_big_category,
        body,
        status
        FROM DB_TABLE;
```

And the list output is running in **js file**.

```js
$(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url : "/dblistdata",
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        data: data,
        timeout: 10000
    }).done(function (result) {
        if(result.resultCode == "S000"){
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var tableBody =  '<tr>'
                        + '<td>' + result.messagelist[i].type_big_category + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + result.messagelist[i].type_mid_category + '</td>'
                        + '<td>'
                        + '<label class="checkbox" for="checkbox' + i + '">'
                        + '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox' + i + '" checked="checked" />'
                        + '</label>'
                        + '</td>'
                        + '<td>'
                        +   '<textarea class="form-control push-text">"' + result.messagelist[i].body + '"</textarea>'
                        + '</td>'
                        + '<td>'
                        +   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>'
                        +   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="deletebutton'+ i + '">delete</button>'
                        + '</td>'
                        + '</tr>';

                $('#tbody').append(tableBody);
                var btn[i] = document.getElementById('deletebutton[i]');
                btn[i].disabled = 'disabled';
            }
        }else{
            alert(result.resultMsg);
        }
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    })

});
```

And I have to show the list in the **jsp file.**

```
<form class="smart-form">
    <table class="tb-regist" id="eeMsg">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sortation</th>
                <th>situation</th>
                <th>check</th>
                <th colspan="2">message</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

[image: not see]

It has to be output in this way. How do you print it out? Please help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using Java so probably you are using servlet-like request processor. So you have at least two approachs to make your view, the third one is just a suggestion that I've found useful :

- Add your list as an attribute of the request for your JSP and use JSTL
- Get your list with asynchronous javascript request (i.e. fetch or XHR)
- Use third-party library (like Boostrap-tables)

## Add your list as an attribute of the request for your JSP and use JSTL

**Servlet**

Add your list to the request attribute.

```java
public void doGet( // or doPost
    HttpServletRequest req, 
    HttpServletResponse res
) throws ServletException, IOException  {
    List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    req.setAttribute("myList", myList);
}
```

**JSP**

Iterate with JSTL through your list and call whatever object attribute you want for each cell of each row of your table.

```html
<form class="smart-form">
    <table class="tb-regist" id="eeMsg">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sortation</th>
                <th>situation</th>
                <th>check</th>
                <th colspan="2">message</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${ myList }" var="object">
                <tr>
                    <td>${ object.seq_no }</td>
                    <td>${ object.type_big_category }</td>
                    <td>
                        <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox01">
                            <input type="checkbox" 
                                   name="checkbox" 
                                   id="checkbox01" 
                                   checked="checked" />
                            <i/>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea class="form-control push-text">body</textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" 
                                class="btn btn-primary">
                            save
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" 
                                class="btn btn-default"
                                id='deletebutton'>
                            delete
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Don't forget JSTL declaration though!

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

## Get your list with asynchronous javascript request (i.e. fetch or XHR)

**Servlet**

Add your list to the request attribute but as JSON format, you can use `org.json.JSONArray` from [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813) library.

```java
public void doPost( // or doGet
    HttpServletRequest req, 
    HttpServletResponse res
) throws ServletException, IOException  {
    List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(myList);
    res.setContentType("application/json");
    res.getWriter().print(jsonArray);
    res.getWriter().flush();
    res.getWriter().close();
    res.flushBuffer();
}
```

**JSP**

Just static HTML, table will be build with javascript.

```html
<form class="smart-form">
    <table class="tb-regist" id="eeMsg">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sortation</th>
                <th>situation</th>
                <th>check</th>
                <th colspan="2">message</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

Parse your response as JSON and iterate over to build your table with [HTMLTableElement](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-64060425).

```
// XHR post function
var sendXHRPost = void 0;
{
    sendXHRPost = function (url, params, callback) {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('POST', url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (http.readyState === 4) {
                callback(http.status, http.responseText);
            }
        }
        http.send(params);
    }
}
// get your table data
var fetchTableData = void 0;
{
    fetchTableData = function () {
        sendXHRPost(
            'myURL', 
            // maybe you don't pass parameters to fetch your table?
            'parameterName=parameterValue', 
            function (responseStatus, responseText) {
                makeTable(responseStatus, JSON.parse(responseText);
            }
        );
    }
}
// formatter for your textarea cell
var textAreaCellFormatter = void 0;
{
    textAreaCellFormatter = function (rowId) {
        return '<textarea class="form-control push-text">'
            + rowId 
            + '</textarea>';
    }
}
// formatter for your buttons cell
var buttonsCellFormatter = void 0;
{
    buttonsCellFormatter = function (rowId) { 
        return  '<button type="button" '
            + 'class="btn btn-primary">'
            + 'save'
            + '</button>'
            + '<button type="button" '
            + 'class="btn btn-default" '
            + 'id="deletebutton'+rowId+'">'
            + 'delete'
            + '</button>';
    }
}
// build your table
var makeTable = void 0;
{
    makeTable = function (status, jsonResponse) {
        var table = document.getElementById("eeMsg");
        // Delete table content in case it was already loaded
        for (var i = 1 ; i < table.rows.length ; i++) {
            table.deleteRow(i); 
        }
        for (var i = 0 ; i < table.tBodies.length ; i++) {
            table.removeChild(table.tBodies[i]); 
        }
        // Create tbody
        var tBody = table.createTBody();
        // Handle internal server error
        if (status != 200) {
            var row = tBody.insertRow();
            var cell = row.insertCell(0);
            cell.colSpan = "4";
            cell.innerHTML = "Error while fetching data.";
        }
        // Handle no data found
        else if (jsonResponse.length === 0) {
            var row = tBody.insertRow();
            var cell = row.insertCell(0);
            cell.colSpan = "4";
            cell.innerHTML = "No data found.";
        }
        // All fine, build your table
        else {
            for(var i = 0 ; i < jsonResponse.length ; i++) {
                var row = tBody.insertRow();
                row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = jsonResponse[i].seq_no;
                row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = jsonResponse[i].type_big_category;
                row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = textAreaCellFormatter(i);
                row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = buttonsCellFormatter(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
// Execute your function on page loading.
(function () { fetchTableData(); })();
```

## Use third-party library (like [Boostrap-tables](https://bootstrap-table.com/))

**Servlet**

Same has above.

**JSP**

```
<!-- libs and css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<!-- your table in your body, not builded yet -->
<table id="eeMsg"
       data-toolbar="#toolbar"
       data-toggle="table"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-search="true"
       data-url="yourFetchURLWithJSONResponse">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="seq_no">Sortation</th>
            <th data-field="type_big_category">situation</th>
            <th>check</th>
            <th colspan="2">message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: How do I set it in javascript when using bootstrap seems simple?

Comment: Just import javascripts files and css from bootstrap-table and set data-url and other dataset attributes for your table like in the example above. Imported bootstrap-tables javascript will do the cooking for you! i.e. `<table id="eeMsg"
       data-toolbar="#toolbar"
       data-toggle="table"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-search="true"
       data-url="dblistdata"><!-- your table headers here --><table>`

Comment: What does this mean?  `Your table heads here `

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand because I'm beginning web page.

Comment: It means you have to write your headers here as I didn't write it due to the lack of space in comments. Like in your example : `<thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sortation</th>
                <th>situation</th>
                <th>check</th>
                <th colspan="2">message</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to fetch the data to the table. Your `ajax` code should be like the following. After getting all the results it will show in your table.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/dblistdata",
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(result) {
            console.log(result);

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var tableBody = "
                    <tr>
                        <td>" + result[i].seq_no + "</td>
                        <td>" + result[i].type_big_category + "</td>
                        <td>
                            <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox01">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox01" checked="checked" />
                            </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea class="form-control push-text">" + result[i].body + "</textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="deletebutton">dlete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ";

                $('#tbody').append(tableBody);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Your `HTML` code should be like this,

```
<form class="smart-form">
    <table class="tb-regist" id="eeMsg">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sortation</th>
                <th>situation</th>
                <th>check</th>
                <th colspan="2">message</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

I assume that you are using `JQuery`. But if not add [JQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js).

Comment: I'm have error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` line is **var= tableBody = "**   i'm updated question

Comment: I solved the error by using a string, but I can't see the data. What is the reason? Your question has been updated.

Comment: @helpmesolution What about this? `resultCode `? Can you post the result that coming?

Comment: I can bring it. Come into the conditional door.I can also get this price. `result.messagelist[0].type_big_category`

Comment: Can you post the result here? I need to check that.

Comment: I changed the data and solved it. `result.messagelist.length;` But I can't see `checkbox`

Comment: If you look at my question, you can see the result that you can't see.

Comment: I didn't try the code to the person who answered the other answer below, but I chose the answer because I thought it would help people. So I don't think I can give you a grade. I'm sorry. Thank you for your help.